# Class 'Imagick' not found - PHP and Windows

Tags: php, image, imagick, php-extension

I need to use Imagick to convert an image using PHP on Xampp and Windows. I am getting this error: `Class 'Imagick' not found` . These are the steps I took:

1. Downloaded Imagick dll and placed it in the `/ext` folder (the folder that loads the modules from php.ini)
2. Enabled the extension in the php.ini
3. Added the other dll files that come with Imagick to the /php folder (they are in the correct directory because after placing them, the errors indicating they are missing were gone).
4. installed ImageMagick on the device.
5. checked `php -m` , and can see imagick in the list.
6. checked `phpinfo()` for (imagick) **still not available**.

I have confirmed (from phpinfo) that the DLLs I am downloading match the build I have for php (PHP 5.5, x86, thread-secure, VC 11).

I still cannot get it to work. I have a feeling it is a mismatch between the downloaded modules and the server. My system is 64x but Apache and php are 86x (as seen from phpinfo).

Comment: What does php-error log say? Is not found? Mismatch? Did your restart Xampp after added files and updated php.ini?

Comment: extensions_loaded() ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php

Comment: Yes, I did restart but that did not solve it.
extensions_loaded is equivalent to checking php -m, which shows imagick in the list.